# Find the sum of a column by grouping two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For this dataset, i want to find the sum of Value(£) for each combination of the
three columns together for Year, Length Group and Port of Landing. So for example, one sum value will be for the year 2016, the Length group 10m&Under and the Port of Landing Aberdaran.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  The pandas documentation for `groupby` is pretty thorough.

Comment: `output = df.groupby(["Year","Length Group","Port of Landing"])["Value(£)"].sum()`

Comment: I want the value column to be the sum of values for that said groupby. for some reason it has no column name

Comment: I want the output to be in a dataframe including the Year, Length group, Port of Landing and the overall value for the combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the response you have back to @berkayln, I think you want to project that column back to your original dataframe...
Does this suit your need ?

```
df['sumPerYearLengthGroupPortOfLanding']=df.groupby(['Year','Length Group','Port of Landing'])['Value(£)'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```

Comment: Thank you , this works perfectly. Sorry if i didnt make that clear!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
dataframe.groupby(['Year','Length Group','Port of Landing'])['Value(£)'].sum()
```

That should work.

Comment: Is this still in the form of a dataframe?

Comment: This is a pandas serie which is a column of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` to aggregate the data.

```py
# Change the order if you want a different hierarchy 
grp_cols = ["Year", "Length Group", "Port of Landing"]
df.groupby(grp_cols)["Value(£)"].sum()
```

You can also do them one-by-one as such:

```py
for col in grp_cols:
    df.groupby(col)["Value(£)"].sum()
```

You can also use `.loc` to get 2016 only.

```py
df.loc[df.Year == 2016]["Value(£)"].sum()
```

The `pd.DataFrame.groupby` functionality allows you to aggregate using other functions other than `.sum`, including customized functions that operate on the sub-dataframes.